# MVC 4 Authorize Controller Attribute Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roleprovider, authorize, windows-authentication

I've created the default MVC 4 Intranet Application and configured it to use Windows Authentication as follows. I'm trying to Authenticate my roles against Active Directory

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" enabled="true">
</roleManager>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

When I decorate the controller with the following attribute for users it works fine because it's using windows authentication

```
[Authorize(Users=@"domain\username")]
```

When I try to decorate it with the following attribute for Roles, it tells me I'm not authorized. I've tried specifying the full path of the roles such as `domain\ou container\ ou container\` etc all the way down to the specific group, but it still doesn't work.

I'm not sure what role provider it's using even though I specified AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"domain\role")]
```

I guess my question boils down to how can I get it to authenticate against AD Groups. If you can point me in the right direction, I sure would appreciate. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I haven't found the answer that works for me yet.

Comment: have you tried `[Authorize(Roles = @"role")] without the `domain\` part?

Comment: I figured it out.  I was using only a Group to authorize against.  I needed to use the AuthorizationGroups in AD.  UGH!!!!!